# Junit Framework Unit Tests : Mockito.doNothing() doesn't work as expected while mocking void methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, void

I am facing an issue where in the "Mockito.doNothing()" doesn't seem to mock the method as expected. 
In the below code (pseudo code) "execution of functionC" returns an exception.
And i am trying to test FunctionA by mocking classB and it's methods. 
I had expected the Mockito.verify to succeed considering that functionB has been mocked to return to the caller immediately ( without executing functionC ). 
But testFunctionA() runs into an exception ( thrown by functionC ), Remember functionC isn't supposed to be executed ( due to the mocking of functionB with Mockito.doNothing() ).

Could you please let me know if i am missing something? Any other alternate methods to mock void methods ( to return immediately ) would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vamsi.

```
public class classA {
  public void functionA() {
    int localA;
    String localB;
    B b = new B();
    b.functionB(localA, localB);
   }
 }

public class classB {
  public void functionB(int a, String b) {
    functionC(a, b);
  }
}

public class testClassA {
private classA objectA = new classA();

@Mock
classB objectB;

@Test
public void testFunctionA() {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(objectB).functionB(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString());
    objectA.functionA();
    Mockito.verify(objectB, Mockito.times(1)).functionB(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think functionC will not execute? You are not mocking it ...

Answer (score 2):

You never inject the `classB` mock in the instance of `classA`, the class under test. So the recorded behavior will not be effective as you manipulate the object under test :

```
private classA objectA = new classA();
```

You could pass `ObjectB` either in the constructor of `ClassA` or in the `functionA()` method.

For example to do that with the method :

```
public void functionA(ClassB classB) {
    int localA;
    String localB;   
    classB.functionB(localA, localB);
}
```

and in your test :

```
objectA.functionA(objectB);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you never passing your mock of `classB` to the object under test of `classA`. Please also refer to [Mockito Object Creation Mocking Guide](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation)

Answer (score 0):

`classA` creates a new instance of `B` (I guess this should rather be `classB`) on each `functionA` invocation. Thus it will never use the `classB` mock.

I would suggest to make `classB` an instance field of `classA`

```
public class classA {

   classB b = new classB();

   public void functionA() {
      int localA = 1;
      String localB = "";

      b.functionB(localA, localB);
   }
}
```

and use `InjectMocks`

```
public class testClassA {

  @InjectMocks
  private classA objectA = new classA();

  @Mock
  classB objectB;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunctionA() {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(objectB).functionB(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
    objectA.functionA();
    Mockito.verify(objectB, Mockito.times(1)).functionB(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
  }
}
```